# Send Parameters in a POST request in axios

Tags: javascript, php, express, post, axios

I am new to express framework, in my application I use axios to send HTTP requests to a php server. I am using following code to send POST requests to a php page with parameters 'username' and 'password' as described in the axios documentation. But my php server does not receive any POST parameters, because

```
echo($_POST['username']);
```

doesn't return anything. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here & instruct me to correct this without changing the php files? following is the code which I used to send HTTP POST requests

```js
axios.post('http://localhost/test/login.php', {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'user@test'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation for axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format):

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON.

PHP doesn't automatically parse JSON formatted requests.

You'll need to either send data in a format that PHP will decode into `$_POST` as described in the documentation linked above, or write your PHP so it can handle a JSON encoded request (as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/19068)).